# JPA shared join table between entities

Tags: hibernate, jpa, database-design

For JPA with hibernate, is it possible for 2 or more different entities to have the same association (One to many or many to many)? Let say Table A and Table B both have an association to Table D via a join table Table C

or I need to define a separate join table for each entity?

I understand that the foreign key for both table A and B must be unique.

Comment: Only if A and B are in the same class hierarchy... eg if B extends A and A defines the association.

Comment: If you add a ERD snapshot pic, there will be more help.

Comment: MattR, totally agreed. if A and B are not in the same class hierarchy, both A and B have to use different join tables.